# I need help opening this light cover

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, light

How do I remove this cover? It turns a little bit but doesn't screw off. There isn't much give for me to try pry an edge out. I'm in the verge of smashing it lol

[image]

Comment: use a kitchen sink plunger as a giant suction cup

Comment: "it turns a little bit" suggests that you turn it and then pull down. But sense it is not mine and i think it is ugly i am not opposed to smashing it. Cover it with tape and smash, Were goggles. Legal disclaimer: i am not suggesting you smash it i just think you could smash it.

Comment: Haha that's not a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

It might pull straight down with spring clips holding it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Tape. Take a piece about say 6" long and fold it in the middle sticking about 1" together, now take the tails and stick that to the cover so that you have a handle. Do two of them if you need to